# Text art or ASCII art? Which tag should we have?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [tag wiki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/ascii-art/info) for [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) says

> This challenge involves creating or parsing pictures using text characters as the paint. Typically this uses only 95 printable (from a total of 128) characters defined by the ASCII Standard from 1963.

This makes it clear that "ASCII" here refers to the original 128 characters, and not to one of the various 256 character extensions. However, the tag is sometimes applied to challenges which are more general "text art", using characters not found in the original 128. In general, we may have challenges that use text from a wider set, perhaps some subset of unicode.

The tag [text-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-art) was [proposed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32638471#32638471). Would it be useful to have a broader tag? Is this a good candidate for such a tag? Should this replace [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) or accompany it, like [math](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) accompanies [arithmetic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic)? Should the [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) tag wiki be extended to include general text art in addition to strict ASCII? Is there some other word that sums up the whole set of letters, numbers and graphical characters better than "text"?

Comment: I'll think about this a bit more before posting an answer, but my gut reaction is that `ascii-art` should be extended to all character-based images. It's a fairly common term (I've never heard of text art before) and several of our tags apply to challenges that don't really fit the definition (`quine` for non-quines, `kolmogorov-complexity`, etc.).

Comment: @Dennis That last one... Basically, I can see that [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenges often use STDIN input, while the definition of the tag is the size of the program relative to the size of the constant output (in bytes).

Answer (score 22):

Adding emphasis to the quote from the tag wiki:

> This challenge involves **creating or parsing pictures using text characters** as the paint. **Typically** this uses only 95 printable (from a total of 128) characters defined by the ASCII Standard from 1963.

Without even modifying the wiki it seems that the tag covers art created with larger character sets, or even character sets which aren't supersets of ASCII. This is in line with general usage: e.g. [Wikipedia:ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ASCII_art&oldid=741401357) says:

> The term is also loosely used to refer to text based visual art in general.

So it's not necessary to create a new tag.

Comment: The name is disingenuous though - it doesn't match the description.

Answer (score -5):

### Make [text-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-art) a tag, make [ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) a tag synonym

[ascii-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ascii-art) implies that only ASCII characters will be used, which is not always the case. [text-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-art) is much less confusing. Since "ASCII art" is common terminology, there's no harm in keeping it around as a synonym, but [text-art](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-art) is much more descriptive and should be the primary tag name.